# Cheapest mobile operator in Europe

Tags: budget, europe, cellphones, mobile-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to avoid data roaming fees when travelling abroad?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-are-the-best-ways-to-avoid-data-roaming-fees-when-travelling-abroad)

Is where any default cheap mobile provider across Europe?
I want to buy sim-card in one country (East or Nord Europe), and use it in other (West Europe). Is it possible?

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25/international-cell-phone-data-plans

Comment: Update: Since [EU roaming regulations change](http://ec.europa.eu/digital-agenda/en/roaming) (effective late 2013) any of given answers are right now not any longer valid or correct. You can now buy a SIM card in **any** European country, activate it's roaming plan (if it is not already activated) and use it at the same, flat rates across entire European Union zone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Europe does have per country operators, there are [some](http://www.truphone.com/) [operators](http://www.abroadband.com/) that will provide very low roaming rates. I've not tried any of them though, and not all of them cover the whole of Europe yet.

Be aware that some countries (such as the UK) have a very competitive Pay As You Go market with very cheap flexible sims available with bundled data etc, while other countries, such as France, are a lot less competitive.

Answer (score 7):

No it isn't - Europe have per country operators

Answer (score 4):

Vodafone are the only company I know of that have their own network across essentially all of Europe. Their roaming prices are not super cheap, and are dependent on where you buy your SIM card. If you buy your SIM card in the UK, the prices can be accessed [here](http://www.vodafone.co.uk/personal/price-plans/managing-my-costs/travelling-abroad/). A calling card may be a better option.