# How can I use my US iPhone (AT&T) in a foreign country, specifically Iceland, without paying through the nose?

Tags: budget, cellphones, iceland, roaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to avoid data roaming fees when travelling abroad?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-are-the-best-ways-to-avoid-data-roaming-fees-when-travelling-abroad)

I would like to be able to use my iPhone for text messages, short voice calls, and a few 10's of Megabytes of data access while in Iceland this September. Is there a way to do that inexpensively, on the cheap?

Is it even possible?

When we were in Canada (CANADA!!) in October, 2009, we used our phones for about 6 minutes of voice calls, a handful of text messages and looking up our location / directions with the Maps app *once* over the cellular network and it cost us $90+ for the "privilege" after they tallied it up on our bill the next month. I was astounded at how much it cost.

I didn't even bring my phone with me when we went to Mexico recently. I was afraid of how much it might cost me.

Comment: I'm going to vote for a re-open here.  The other question is about phones from Germany which are unlocked (and therefore much easier to get international plans for by replacing the SIM).  This question is specifically about US iPhones which are locked by default and thereby are not amenable to the suggestions from the other question.  @DLRdave: I suggest you edit the question to clarify that you cannot simply replace your SIM (unless of course you have jailbroken/unlocked your phone).

Comment: You might have some luck asking this question (or searching for similar answers) on [Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com), the Stack Exchange site about using Apple stuff.