# Will my European phone (Nokia 1208) work in the USA?

Tags: usa, cellphones

I have a Nokia 1208 bought in Sweden with a pre-paid SIM-card from Telia. Will I be able to use my mobile phone in the USA? I'm not talking about expensive roaming fees or so, just whether it's possible at all. How can I find out apart from actually going there?

See also: [Do American cellphones work in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1378/2509)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [phone specification](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_1208-1977.php), the phone has two versions:

- GSM 900 / 1800
- GSM 850 / 1900 - US version

Obviously you have the EU version (GSM 900/1800) which will not work with the US networks which are (GSM 850/1900).

For more information:
[GSM Bands information by country](http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html).