# Should I use a "burner" phone when visiting the US?

Tags: usa, cellphones, borders, electronic-items, privacy

I'm a New Zealand citizen and I might soon be visiting to the US on short notice for business. I've [heard that](https://www.theguardian.com/law/2017/mar/27/us-customs-digital-device-searches-privacy-lawsuit-passwords) [the US](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/can-us-border-agents-search-your-phone-at-the-airport-2017-2?r=US&IR=T) [have started](https://www.npr.org/2017/04/11/523313829/more-travelers-are-being-asked-for-their-cellphones-and-passwords-entering-u-s) [to frequently](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/what-if-u-s-border-agents-ask-your-cellphone-n742511) [search cellphones](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/us-customs-agents-are-searching-more-cellphones--including-those-belonging-to-americans/2018/01/05/0a236202-f247-11e7-b3bf-ab90a706e175_story.html). I'm not very comfortable handing over my phone and lock code to US customs - as well as copying the contents of the phone (including passwords, giving them unlimited access to all of my accounts) if it's out of my sight they could install extra software or hardware.

But obviously, a cellphone is a must when traveling overseas. Would it be a reasonable idea to get a second, cheap cellphone just for this trip?

Or am I being excessively paranoid? I've never been to or through the US before, only heard the horror stories.

I'll also be bringing a company laptop, but I'm not too concerned about this since I've deliberately avoided storing personal data or credentials on it, and it's a US company.

Comment: Your definition of frequently probably isn’t the same as mine. One of the articles you linked to says it happens less than 0.01% of the time. However, there’s probably a bias if you’re a middle-eastern male between the ages of 18 and 40 or something like that (or you do have such apparent origin).

Comment: I travelled four weeks in the USA in 2013, without any functioning mobile phone.  It is not "obviously a must".  You can do without.

Comment: Another risk to factor in is that a "clean" device may invite extra scrutiny - the perverse "what do you have to hide?" mentality.

Comment: You are being mislead by purposely hysterical fake news.

Comment: @gerrit If my employer asked me to do a four week business trip without access to 3G, I would not give an accommodating answer.

Comment: Coincidentally, I found out my phone is likely to brick itself any day now (it's a Nexus 5X) so I may want to get a new phone *anyway* just so I won't find myself with a bricked phone while I'm there.

Comment: @Calchas If your employer asks you to do a four week business trip and wants you to have access to 3G for work purposes, it should be your employers responsibility to provide you with a phone.  If they do not require you to have such access but you want to have it anyway, it is your own responsibility.  Personally, I have never owned a 3G capable phone and use [my Nokia 1208](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13110/2509) rarely.

Comment: @pseudon: Clean device is easily explained: "I didn't bring my main phone.  It's expensive and I'm afraid of having it stolen." or "I didn't bring my main phone.  Its radio doesn't work in (country of destination), so I got a travel phone that's compatible"

Answer (score 7):

If the CBP feels the need, they will either read through your mail and other apps manually on the device, or dump the device using something like one of these Cellebrite devices. You can see a CBP documentary where this is used on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTlp5HW3fiU):
[image]

I've entered the US dozens if not hundreds of times and nobody has ever asked to look at my phones, but who knows how likely it will be for you. You can of course take precautions such as wiping and reloading your phone, implementing [pair-locking](https://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?p=2589) on an iphone, etc., but it's all down to your risk appetite whether you wish to do this.

Comment: Pair-locking was an interesting read. One must assume that TLAs (US or their foreign equivalent) are aware of this and that they will be able to tell whether a device is pair-locked upon inspection. Don't you think it's riskier to bear a pair-locked device (without its unlocking pair) than a clean phone? A pair-locked phone is pretty much like encrypted storage: "you must be carrying something there that interests us" and even worse, you can't give up the key to unlock it.