# Lots of cell phone spamming after a trip to the US from Canada. Is this to be expected?

Tags: usa, privacy

This is related to [usa - Should I use a "burner" phone when visiting the US? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/111725/103831) but not for border control reasons.

---

I did a road trip through the USA, from Canada, for 5 days.

During that trip I:

- signed up for data roaming with my Canadian cellular provider. The roaming was done on a large US cellular provider (one whose news coverage is usually rather unflattering). Therefore they knew my number.
- only gave out my phone number twice to hotels, in response to "where can we contact you?" questions. I usually purposefully switch the last 2 digits of my phone number to avoid spamming (e.g. 37 rather than 73) but figured I wanted to be notified if I forgot something.

Upon my return, I have easily 10-20x the usual number of spam robocalls. I have an unlisted number and only give it out when needed so I usually don't get bothered much. These spam calls are from numbers not in my contacts, don't leave any messages, not easily found on reverse lookups. From different cities in British Columbia, where I don't know anyone, but also from other provinces.

I usually have 3-4 of those a month, at most. First day I was back in Canada, I had 7 or 8 and have been getting a few a day since. Not a huge hassle, the phone is set up to send unrecognized numbers straight to voice mail, without ringing.

Is this something that can be expected from only giving out your number twice and being signed up for roaming?  I assume that one of the hotels or the cellular company passed on my number to marketing third parties.

I am not expecting a definitive answer, but, well, if other travelers have had the same experience we can all learn to be more careful when traveling in the US. And if it didn't happen to anyone else, I'll chalk it up to a coincidence.

P.S. I assume this would be more likely to happen to Canadians as I can't see the attraction for US companies to enter into lots of marketing list arrangements with random European or Asian countries.

Comment: (Borat accent) US of A, beste countri ona planet!

Comment: "I usually purposefully switch the last 2 digits of my phone number" -- that must make the owner of that phone number very happy indeed. And you complain about getting spammed.

Comment: *"I usually purposefully switch the last 2 digits of my phone number"* they've thought of that. You're achieving nothing. Billions of dollars a year are spent on the world's greatest software engineers and software scientists to make spam work.

Comment: I live in the US and I give my number out as little as possible. I've seen a significant uptick in the number of spam calls/texts over the last 24 months or so. If I don't recognize the number, I let it go to voice mail. If it's important and legitimate, they'll leave a message and I'll call back. 99.99% of the time, there's no message. I'm always amused by the calls/texts saying my FifthThird Bank debit card has been locked - I've never had an account with them and don't think I've ever even used one of their ATM machines. I guess _some_ people respond and make it worth it...

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, I am aware of that.  I've mostly rationalized it - to myself - by a) maybe the number is unassigned, b) if they'd called the caller would quickly drop the matter as it is not me and c) they wouldn't call, would they?  I often opt out of giving numbers out entirely, in Canada (sure as heck will in the US).  But often I find refusing numbers results in a tedious scripted exchange reminding you of all the things they can't help you with wo it.  Tell you want, maybe I need to find an unassigned 3-digit area code to play with.  Esp if its similar to my 604 for plausible denial.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica the "555-[0100-0199]" range is unassigned in any area code. Any number (XXX) 555-01YY is an invalid number. You can see that being in use in TV shows, you could also try that when forced to give a number to people who you never want to call you. Some might identify it, but for some it might work.

Comment: @littleadv I'll give that a try.  644, close to 604, is unassigned, but citing will sound wrong to anyone in my area so not as helpful as I first thought.  A weird number in my area code will slip by, if not caught by software.

Comment: I just set my phone to automatically send all unknown numbers to voicemail.

Comment: You could always use [867-5309](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WTdTwcmxyo)! :D _Actually, no, don't do that. People stuck with that number got thousands of phone calls in all sorts of area codes when that song came out_

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Have you considered setting up a second number through eg Google Voice and setting it to silent? That way you could still check it for SMS/voicemail as needed, without inadvertently signing someone else up for spam.

Comment: @MiloP Well, I would certainly consider all sorts of things, *next time I go to the US*.  I was surprised by this mess.  [Canadian law doesn't allow nearly the freedom to disclose personal info to third parties.](https://www.priv.gc.ca/en/privacy-topics/privacy-laws-in-canada/the-personal-information-protection-and-electronic-documents-act-pipeda/p_principle/principles/p_use/) : businesses aren't freely allowed to sell your contact info.  I am not so much worried about this right now, as I was trying to figure out what happened in the first place.  And considering this of interest to travelers

Comment: This doesn't really answer you question, so leaving it as a comment, but those numbers from British Columbia are most likely being spoofed. This is normally what phone scammers do, as it makes them somewhat harder to track and, more importantly, no one would answer the phone when the caller ID said the call was from Cameroon. Scammers often pick random numbers from your country, state/province, or even local area to spoof when calling you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I assume that one of the hotels or the cellular company passed on my number to marketing third parties.

This.

In the US, there's very little protection for personal information and it is being traded by everyone and everywhere. If you gave your information to a US merchant, they'll sell it. In some States you can restrict who they can share it with, but you'd need to proactively do that and they'd tell you "we'll stop sharing it within 30 days", which is essentially meaningless. In California you can [demand to delete your personal information](https://oag.ca.gov/privacy/ccpa), under certain conditions, but not in other States. Which is also meaningless in this case since they already have sold it.

> p.s. I assume this would be more likely to happen to Canadians as I can't see the attraction for US companies to enter into lots of marketing list arrangements with random European or Asian countries.

It is as likely to happen to Canadians as to anyone else. But with regard to robocalls, because of the numbering system and costs, it is likely that Canadians would be affected much more than anyone else.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151679/discussion-on-answer-by-littleadv-lots-of-cell-phone-spamming-after-a-trip-to-th); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

> Lots of cell phone spamming after a trip to the US from Canada. Is this to be expected?

It's not exactly what you're looking for but I *live* in the US and have given out my number to 100+ vendors over my time here. I've checked my voicemail records and I estimate I get around 1 robocall a month (I set my phone to send all unknown numbers straight to voicemail). It used to be more frequent a few years ago but these days it's no longer a significant nuisance.

That being said, my number is registered on [DoNotCall.gov](https://www.donotcall.gov/), which probably helps reduce the amount of spam. They don't accept Canadian numbers unfortunately, so if you're already registered with the [Canadian equivalent](https://lnnte-dncl.gc.ca/en) there's not much you can do.

Comment: I'm registered with its Canadian equivalent, after the kinks got sorted out (initially the spammers were using it as a databank of active numbers ;-).  I do wonder if donotcall (US) penalties apply to calling non-US numbers tho.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica you're right, they don't take Canadian numbers unfortunately :/

Comment: Same. I live in the U.S. and have undoubtedly given my phone number to _thousands_ of companies both all over the U.S. and around various parts of the world. I get fewer spam calls than OP mentioned getting in Canada before visiting the U.S. This is almost certainly a case of coincidence or OP's number getting on a spam list by other means, not one of 3 companies selling a phone number to scammers.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The Do Not Call Registry (or any country's equivalent thereof) rather by definition only affects legal companies conducting actual marketing (or otherwise non-criminal activity.) Scammers on another continent do not care whether or not they are violating your country's (or usually even their country's) data protection laws.