# unlock a AT&T phone outside US

Tags: usa

I bought an AT&T locked phone in Europe, second hand,got authorization to unlock it.Can this unlock process be completed outside the US? Just want to make sure it works BEFORE traveling...

Comment: Will the European phone work in US? Please see [Do American cellphones work in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1378/do-american-cellphones-work-in-europe) Note that question was asked 8 years ago.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the mechanics of unlocking a mobile phone do not constitute a travel problem

Comment: It can, but it is typically not immediate.