# Is there any 3g data package that works across Europe?

Tags: europe, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choices for prepaid GSM data with laptop tethering in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/choices-for-prepaid-gsm-data-with-laptop-tethering-in-europe)

> I will travel to Europe this year. Is there any 3G with data package
>   that will be work on most of this selected cities (London - Amsterdam
>   - Munich - Venice - Paris ) How much it would be?

[Question originally by Rudy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/is-there-any-3g-with-data-package-that-will-be-work-across-europe-how-to-go-t), but was combined with another question so I split it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the solutions to this seem quite limited.

[Droam50](http://www.droam.nl/en/prices/) will provide you with 50MB of data per day €27.50 for the first day and €3.50 per day afterwards. Alternatively, you can receive 1GB for €65 and €45 per GB (or part thereof!) over 30 days. Not very flexible at all. Various countries have [certain limitations](http://www.droam.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Coverage-and-price-list-mobile-internet-Droam.pdf) - but it works quite well across Europe. Unfortunately, you also have to pay expensive shipping costs for receiving and returning a [Droam](http://www.droam.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/shipping-costs-Droam.pdf). In Australia, it would cost me €68 just in shipping costs.

Another option seems to be to obtain a pre-paid SIM in Europe and add a booster. [T-mobile](http://support.t-mobile.co.uk/help-and-support/index?page=home&cat=USING_THE_INTERNET_ABROAD&pcateg=HELPANDADVICE) has boosters that cost between £1 for 3MB for a day, or £5 for 20MB over a week, or £10 for 50MB over 30 days. You may need to pay for some normal credit as well. You may also want to add a [booster](http://www.t-mobile.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/price-plans/pay-as-you-go/boosters/) for normal calls.

Comment: the "certain limitations" link is quite outdated now: http://www.droam.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Prijslijst-landenlijst-engels-per-11-7-2012.pdf and so are the prices (as you can see on this same PDF)