# Can I buy local prepaid mobile number in any Schengen country without having permanent residence proof there?

Tags: europe, amsterdam, communication, internet, mobile-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to avoid data roaming fees when travelling abroad?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-are-the-best-ways-to-avoid-data-roaming-fees-when-travelling-abroad)

I will be going to Amsterdam only for 3 days from India. I use **iPhone 4** and a prepaid mobile plan with 3G/2G internet(prepaid) option. I want to talk to India sometime during my stay and I also want to use **Map** on my iPhone to get proper directions.

And if i use my indian mobile number at Amasterdam it will be very costly for international, local call and internet. it will be *.75* euro per minute.

My question is after I reach to Amsterdam. Can i buy a local prepaid mobile number by showing a copy of my passport to make international calls and use 3G/2G internet in my iphone.

**iphone required micro-sim*

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee - my question is how to buy sim in other country. It's not duplicate of the question you mentioned. in that question's answer it's not mentioned in any answer that how we can buy sim? In india to buy a prepaid mobile we need to give our local address proof.

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee - and you can also see the title of both questions. and I already know the answer of the question you mentioned as a duplicate that only way to save data is to buy local sim. and my questions starts after that, How to buy sim?

Comment: You just go and buy one. No proof of any sort required (in the EU).

Comment: Your question title asks about any country (did you mean - every?) and the body is about the specific country. One of things you should fix.